# Importing a project in Unity: "The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development, assets

I'm trying to open a project in Unity made from using AssetRipper on a game. When adding the folder into Unity, I'm forced to open in safe mode, where I get this error in several places in several scripts. The thing is, "Image" is a type in UnityEngine.UI, which was already included.

The code starts:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.Universal;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using UnityEngine.Rendering.Universal;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public BodyScript bodyScript;

    public static Transform globalBody;

    public Image damageOverlay; //error

    public Image lungImage; //error

    public Image lungBackImage; //error
...
```

etc

I tried to open a Unity project acquired through dubious means. I expected to get an incomplete but usable Unity project. I got several of the same error.

Comment: Are you sure that you have referenced the assembly in which that type is declared? Namespaces don't exist physically. They are a logical categorisation of types. It's possible for types in the same namespace to be declared in different assemblies. If you reference one of those assemblies then you can access the types declared within it but the types declared in the other assembly still don't exist as far as your project is concerned. I don't use Unity so I'm not sure what the specific situation is in this case but that's the first thing I'd look at.

Comment: If the library reference were missing then the `using` statement would be squiggly-red as well though 

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I needed to place the required DLLs in the  "ExportedProject\Assets\Plugins" folder